# Thread not stopping issue in Android

Tags: android, service, threadpool, handler, countdowntimer

I am trying to show progress bar on UI from background service through JNI calls. The flow of the app is :

1. A method in background service is called. This method gives the data needed to be shown.
2. A layout is shown through WindowManager by using

   ```
   overLayLayout = (RelativeLayout)   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_body_template_1, null);
   myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) overLayLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_progressBar);
   windowManager.addView(v, layoutParams);
   ```
3. If the layout is already showing then the layout is update by using

   ```
   overLayLayout = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_body_template_1, null);
   myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) overLayLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_progressBar);
   windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, params);
   ```

The flow is repeated whenever a method in background service is called.
 I am showing a horizontal progress bar on the same layout to show the progress of a music.

```
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

              mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalDuration, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        myProgressBar.setProgress((int) (i * 100 /  (totalDuration / 1000)));
                        currentMillis = currentMillis + 1000;

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    Log.v("Log_tag", "tick finished:");

                }

            };
      }
    });
```

My issue here is , when i show a layout it plays the progress bar but if a new layout arrives into background service and if i update the view using updateView method of WindowManager, the window shows two progressBars , the old layout's progressbar and a new progressBar.

The behaviour i am expecting is the old countdowntimer and the thread should not run on the new updated view layout, whereas it is showing old and new progress updates.

Please guide me solving this issue.

Comment: The code you showed is irrelevant. Try to add code where you add progress bar layout.

Comment: @eleven : question edited, this much i can add , the actual code is huge.

Comment: @javabee Where you initialized your : myProgressBar ?

Comment: @eleven : exactly below the LayoutInflater.From , i have updated it in code.

Comment: If you see two instances of `ProgressBars` on the screen, then obviously `windowManager.addView` called twice. Why it's called twice hard to say.

Comment: @eleven . There are no two instances of ProgressBar , i am storing the view in Application class a global variable for the overLayLayout.
the issue here is new Runnable created in the handler is not getting destroyed and keeps running and updating the progressBar.  When the new layout is updated on the current layout , new runnable in handler is also created and hence two runnables are updating the same progressBar.